# Unable to secure routes in Azure Static Web App Preview

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed an Angular 9 application in Azure 'Static Web App Preview'.
The angular routing using the RouteModule is working fine.
But I am unable to secure those routes via [routes.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/routes).
It is as if it is not having any impact at all. Sharing my 'routes.json' file below :

```
{
"routes": [
    {
        "route": "/guest",
        "allowedRoles": [
            "authenticated"
        ]
    },
    {
        "route": "/admin",
        "allowedRoles": [
            "authenticated"
        ]
    },
    {
        "route": "/loginGoogle",
        "serve": "/.auth/login/google?post_login_redirect_uri=/guest"
    },
    {
        "route": "/logout",
        "serve": "/.auth/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=/"
    }
],
"platformErrorOverrides": [
    {
        "errorType": "NotFound",
        "serve": "/loginGoogle"
    },
    {
        "errorType": "Unauthenticated",
        "serve": "/loginGoogle"
    }
]
```

}

[image: My angular's routes are :]

So ideally, when you go to 'guest' via [routerLink]="['/guest']", as per 'routes.json' it should redirect me to '/loginGoogle'. But its not happening.

Kindly let me know what all I doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: Azure Static Web Apps expects your routes.json file to be in the app_artifact_location by default. Or if you have customized the location make sure routes_location property defines the directory location where the routes.json file is found.

Comment: Thanks @rohit. I am referring [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/routes) this for placing the route.json file as I am using Angular and accordingly I have placed it under assets folder.

Comment: Please be aware that the _routes.json_ file is deprecated. Routes, overrides and general configuration of a Azure Static Web Apps are now powered by the [staticwebapp.config.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/static-web-apps/configuration) file.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular router is for client-side (in-app) navigation.  It intercepts changes to the browser's URL, and you use that URL to control which components you want to show or hide in the browser.  So the browser URL does not correspond to a physical path on the server being called - instead your Typescript (or js) code needs to explicitly make its own web requests to pull back the data you need to populate your components.

In contrast, `routes.json` secures server-side physical paths.  For an Angular app you'd primarily use it to secure web requests to your app's API methods under `/api/{method}` folders on the server.  Angular doesn't know about this file.

To secure your client-side Angular routes, you will need to [query the inbuilt `/.auth/me` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/user-information#direct-access-endpoint) in code to pull back the current user's list of roles, and then [implement Angular route guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access) to prevent unauthorized access to your UI routes.